# Difference rows in pandas based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
region     country  Season  stage   statistic   value   ps     ps_vals
alabama      usa    2000    1        median     135.53  0       46.153846
alabama      usa    2001    1        median     138.75  0       30.769231
alabama      usa    2000    3        median     151     91.11    0
alabama      usa    2001    3        median     148.125 46.666  8.333333
california   usa    2000    1        median     83.7191 3.2258  100
california   usa    2001    1        median     92.6332 6.4516  91.666667
california   usa    2000    3        median     49.2137 0       66.666667
california   usa    2001    3        median     108.029 58.0645 58.333333
```

I want to create a new dataframe containing the difference between `ps_vals` where the L.H.S is the value for `stage` 3 and R.H.D is value for `stage` 1. E.g. for Alabama, the `ps_vals` value for `stage` 3 for the year 2000 is 0 and `stage` for year 2000 is 46.153846, therefore the diff. will be -46.153846

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
region     country  Season  ps_vals
alabama      usa    2000    -46.153846
alabama      usa    2001    -22.435898
california   usa    2000    -33.333333
california   usa    2001    -33.333334
```

How to achieve this? I can difference consecutive rows like this: `df['dA'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift(-1)`, but that does not work in this case since the rows might not be consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto merge the dataframe filtered with stage 1 only values against the stage 3 values. Then compute the difference between the now aligned `ps_vals` data:

```
results = df[df.stage==1].merge(df[df.stage==3],
                                on=['region', 'country', 'Season'],
                                suffixes = ('_x', ''))

results.ps_vals -= results.ps_vals_x

results[['region', 'country', 'Season', 'ps_vals']]
Out[56]: 
       region country  Season    ps_vals
0     alabama     usa    2000 -46.153846
1     alabama     usa    2001 -22.435898
2  california     usa    2000 -33.333333
3  california     usa    2001 -33.333334
```